# Filtering and/or grouping data in Angular 5+

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pipe

Unfortunately I have no control on how the API returns data. I get what I get :/

I need help getting my data formatted correctly or possibly using a custom pipe to display it correctly. I've tried different things (mergeMap, filter, group by pipe, etc), but I can't seem to get exactly what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample data

```
[
  { "id": "rossbo01", "first": "Bob", "last": "Ross", "photo": "photo1.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo1"},
  { "id": "rossbo01", "first": "Bob", "last": "Ross", "photo": "photo2.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo2"},
  { "id": "rogersfr02", "first": "Fred", "last": "Rogers", "photo": "photo55.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo55"},
  ...
]
```

Component

```
this.searchService.getData().subscribe(searchResults => {
  this.searchResults = searchResults;
  ....? transform data here or custom pipe in template
});
```

Desired result (show name once and then all associated photos)

```
Bob Ross
    Photo1
    Photo2
Fred Rogers
    Photo55
...
```

What is the most efficient way to get the output I'm looking for? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a pipe's job, you'll just need to scrub your data into a new array and use the scrubbed object array to feed your template. It's not an uncommon task.

Comment: What do you mean? What do 'Photo1', 'Photo2' and 'Photo55' stand for? Are they nodes in HTML DOM or just `console.log` output?

Comment: @KaiserKatze Those are the photoTitles in the sample data I provided.

Comment: Do you get your data asynchronously?

Comment: @KaiserKatze In this case, I don't necessarily have to.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I haven't had the chance to try it yet. I'll let you know...and thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @relyt Have you tried our solutions yet? Please [accept at least one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is my pure RxJS solution :P

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { groupBy, mergeMap, map, toArray, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

let searchResults = [
  { "id": "rossbo01", "first": "Bob", "last": "Ross", "photo": "photo1.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo1"},
  { "id": "rossbo01", "first": "Bob", "last": "Ross", "photo": "photo2.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo2"},
  { "id": "rogersfr02", "first": "Fred", "last": "Rogers", "photo": "photo55.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo55"}
];

from(this.searchResults).pipe(

  // Select necessary attributes
  map(result => {
    //console.log('Result:', result);
    let fname = result['first'];
    let lname = result['last'];
    let photo = result['photoTitle'];
    let rname = [fname, lname].join(' ');
    return { rname, photo };
  }),

  // group objects by `rname` attribute
  groupBy(result => result['rname']),

  // return each item in group as array
  mergeMap(group => {
    //console.log('Group $1:', group);
    return group.pipe(
      toArray(),
    );
  }),

  // Reduce arrays of objects
  map(group => {
    //console.log('Group $2:', JSON.stringify(group));
    let rname = group[0]['rname'];
    return group.reduce((a, b) => {
      return {
        rname: rname,
        photo: [a.photo, b.photo],
      };
    });
  }),

  // Bypass and verify results
  tap(result => console.log('Result:', result)),

).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly use loadash's `groupBy` and `toPairs` functions to group your array data based of on the user's firstname and lastname like below:-

```js
var users = [
  { "id": "rossbo01", "first": "Bob", "last": "Ross", "photo": "photo1.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo1"},
  { "id": "rossbo01", "first": "Bob", "last": "Ross", "photo": "photo2.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo2"},
  { "id": "rogersfr02", "first": "Fred", "last": "Rogers", "photo": "photo55.jpg", "photoTitle": "Photo55"}
]

var result = _.groupBy(users, (user)=> user.first + ' ' + user.last);
result = _.toPairs(result);

console.log('Result: ', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

You can either format or create your own custom pipe based on the function above.

You can refer to the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oikje4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to see a working Angular solution.